# Laravel mock 2 separate Cache::remember in same test

Tags: php, laravel, caching, mocking, phpunit

I am writing a test for a console command.  In the command we make 2 separate api calls to external services which I can mock fine.  But both of those external calls are wrapped in `Cache::remember`.  I want to able to mock both of those Caches in my test, but can't seem to figure it out.  I can only seem to mock the first one.  They have different keys.

So for example, my console command has something like this (which I have simplified for the this)

```
Cache::remember("key-1", (60 * 60) * 24, function () use ($variable) {
    return $this->externalApiAdapter->makeApiCall($variable);
});

Cache::remember("key-2", (60 * 60) * 24, function () {
    return $this->secondExternalApiAdapter->makeAnotherApiCall();
});
```

In my test, I want one of the Caches to return `null`, and the other to return a mocked object.

Here is the first one.

```
Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
    ->with('key-1', (60 * 60) * 24, \Closure::class)
    ->andReturn(null);
```

If I out put the second one in

```
$mockedObject = json_encode([
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
]);

Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
    ->with('key-2', (60 * 60) * 24, \Closure::class)
    ->andReturn((object)json_decode($mockedObject));
```

it sill returns null.

How can I mock the second Cache please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `->once()` for such purposes.

```
// This will be returned the first time Cache::remember is called
Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
    ->once()
    ->with('key-1', (60 * 60) * 24, \Closure::class)
    ->andReturn(null);

$mockedObject = json_encode([
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
]);

// This will be returned the second time Cache::remember is called
Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
    ->once()
    ->with('key-2', (60 * 60) * 24, \Closure::class)
    ->andReturn((object)json_decode($mockedObject));
```

Comment: Are you sure no other `Cache::remember` calls are done before your code is executed?

Comment: yes I'm sure.  i just run a command in the test `$this-artisan('command-key')`;  No other Caches happen.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was me being a bit silly but after a few hours staring at the code and the docs I figured this out.

In my example I don't need to mock the Caches, since the methods inside the Caches are already mocked.  Plus I wasn't returning any value from the Cache methods.

In my command, the `Cache::remember` blocks are in there own method, but I wasnt returning anything.

So this

```
public function methodOne ()
{
    Cache::remember("key-1", (60 * 60) * 24, function () use ($variable) {
        return $this->externalApiAdapter->makeApiCall($variable);
    });
}
public function methodTwo ()
{
    Cache::remember("key-2", (60 * 60) * 24, function () {
        return $this->secondExternalApiAdapter->makeAnotherApiCall();
    });
}
```

got updated to this

```
public function methodOne ()
{
    return Cache::remember("key-1", (60 * 60) * 24, function () use ($variable) {
        return $this->externalApiAdapter->makeApiCall($variable);
    });
}
public function methodTwo ()
{
    return Cache::remember("key-2", (60 * 60) * 24, function () {
        return $this->secondExternalApiAdapter->makeAnotherApiCall();
    });
}
```

In my test I just `Cache::flush();` and continue with the mocked classes I already had in place.